# Direct proof for $a \rightarrow b, c \rightarrow b, d \rightarrow (a \lor c), d \Rightarrow b$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, propositional-calculus

I am just starting learning proofs in my discrete math class. I need to find the direct proof for $a \rightarrow b, c \rightarrow b, d \rightarrow (a \lor c), d \Rightarrow b$.

These are my steps:

1. $ a \rightarrow b [Premise]$
2. $ c \rightarrow b [Premise]$
3. $ (a \rightarrow b) \land (c \rightarrow b) [Conjunction 1, 2] $
4. $ d \rightarrow ( a \lor c) [Premise]$
5. $d \rightarrow b [Constructive Dilemma 3, 4]\square$

Is this a correct proof? I tried multiple ways and nothing worked, but I am not sure if I am using Constructive Dilemma the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint*

Let assume that $⇒$ means $\vdash$, i.e. *consequence*.

Use [Modus Ponens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_ponens) with $d$ and $d \to (a \lor c)$ to derive : $a \lor c$.

Then use [Disjunction elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_elimination) with $a \lor c$ and the first two premises to derive the conclusion $b$.

Comment: where does the $d$ you use in $d \rightarrow (a \lor c)$ come form?

Comment: @Sam - it is the fourth premise in the title of you question.

Comment: Oh ok. I didn't realize you could just use the d by itself. I thought it had to be used in the form $d \Rightarrow b$, but is it because $\Rightarrow b$ is a conclusion so then i can just $d$ as the premise?

Comment: @Sam - What do you mean with $⇒$ ? What are the *premises* and the *conclusion* ?

Comment: I think the premises are $ a \rightarrow b, c \rightarrow b, d \rightarrow (a \lor c)$ and then conclusion is $d \Rightarrow b$

Comment: @Sam - if so, what is the difference between the connectives in $a \to b$ and $d ⇒ b$ ?

Comment: The difference is the $\rightarrow$ vs $\Rightarrow$. Does that mean in $d \Rightarrow b$ that $d$ is a premise too and $b$ is the conclusion